# peewee complex query with case and if

Tags: peewee

I've a table with ROTAs for volunteers:

```
dater      |   vol1id   |  vol2id   |  vol3id  |   vol4id
-----------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------
2017-08-01 |  1         |  13       |  14      |  33 
2017-08-02 |  32        |  150      |  3       |  4
```

One of the old queries check how many volunteers are already up for the day, so it's shown in a HTML table with colors depending on the availabity. This is done this way:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN vol1id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN vol2id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN vol3id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE WHEN vol4id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
FROM rotas 
WHERE (dater BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31')
ORDER BY dater;
```

I'd like to convert this SQL query into peewee filtering, would it be possible to be done with peewee?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did some research but could not make it work. So I took an alternative estrategy, and moved it into a function, just counting the number of fields NOT NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_volunteers(start_date date, end_date date)
  RETURNS TABLE (day date, volunteer_count bigint) AS
$func$
SELECT
   dater,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM (values (T.vol1id), (T.vol2id), (T.vol3id), (T.vol4id)) AS v(col)
      WHERE v.col IS NOT NULL) 
   FROM rotas as T
   WHERE (dater BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
   ORDER BY dater;
$func$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now is much easier, since it's just adding a query this way now:

```
SELECT day, volunteer_count FROM count_volunteers('2017-08-01', '2017-08-31');
```

Which can be now easily used by peewee.